# What type of silicone should I use for caulking the shower corner and the transition from wall tiles to shower base?

Tags: caulking

What type of silicone should I use for caulking the shower corner and the transition from wall tiles to shower base?
I know recommending a product is out of scope here but I am asking about the characteristics of the product that I need

Comment: Something rated for use in showers such at 100% silicone waterproof bathroom

Comment: And flexible. But reading the product info should tell you that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want 100% waterproof silicone for "Bath and Shower". Formulated to prevent mold/mildew, but no special provisions needed for exterior use (sun light, UV, radiant heat).

Silicone cures with the help of moisture in the air, but do not add water.

Some silicone caulking for bath & shower costs more because it is fast drying. This is mostly for contractors that want to install & quickly demonstrate the shower to the customer and get paid. It is not necessary for DIY, unless you have a line-up of teens & inlaws waiting to use the shower.

You also do not need paintable or "30 minute" paint ready properties, nor exterior "30 minute" rain ready.